# Upload with Flask-Uploads and Flask-WTF failing validation

Tags: python, validation, upload, flask, flask-wtforms

I cannot seem to figure out why one field fails where the other succeeds in uploading a file. I can upload a photo just fine... but when it comes to a pdf, I cannot get it to pass validation. I've scoured my code for anything amiss but can't find anything. The funny thing is that I am able to upload a photo via the manual upload set, which doesn't make sense to me. I'm guessing something is off with how I've configured flask-wtf with flask-uploads, but seeing as there's no documentation online on how to use the two together, I just had to do my best.

Any help would be appreciated, as I need to upload pdfs and this has me stumped.

Code is below... thanks a ton!

**config.py**

```
UPLOADED_MANUALS_DEST = "C:/pyprojects/cc/uploads/eq_manuals/"
UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = 'pdf'
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST = "C:/pyprojects/cc/uploads/eq_photos/"
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_ALLOW = 'png, jpg, jpeg'
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, patch_request_class
photos = UploadSet('photos')
manuals = UploadSet('manuals')
configure_uploads(app, (photos, manuals))
patch_request_class(app)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EQForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[Required('Equipment Name is required.')])
    photo = FileField('Equipment Photo', validators=[
        FileAllowed(photos, 'Photo must be a png, jpg, or jpeg!')])
    manual = FileField('Equipment Manual', validators=[
        FileAllowed(manuals, 'Manual must be a pdf!')])
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/admin/equipment/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@roles_accepted('admin')
def equipment():

    eqform = EQForm()

    if eqform.validate_on_submit():
        # os.path.join() the secured filename and the root path from config.py imported as join()
        new_eq = Equipment(name = eqform.name.data)

        if eqform.photo.data:
            photo_path = join(
                app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'],
                secure_filename(eqform.photo.data.filename)
                )

            eqform.photo.data.save(photo_path)
            new_eq.photo_path = photo_path

        if eqform.manual.data:
            manual_path = join(
                app.config['UPLOADED_MANUALS_DEST'],
                secure_filename(eqform.manual.data.filename)
                )

            eqform.manual.data.save(manual_path)
            new_eq.manual_path = manual_path

        db.session.add(new_eq)
        db.session.commit()

    equipment = Equipment.query.all()

    return render_template('equipment.html',
        title="Equipment Database",
        equipment = equipment,
        eqform = eqform
        )
```

**equipment.html**

```
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="eq-field hide" name="eqform">
      {{ eqform.hidden_tag() }}
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              {{ eqform.name.label }}: {{ eqform.name }}
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              {{ eqform.photo.label }}: {{ eqform.photo }} <br>
              <span style="font-size:.75em;">Photo must be a png, jpg, or jpeg.</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              {{ eqform.manual.label }}: {{ eqform.manual }} <br>
              <span style="font-size:.75em;">Manual must be a pdf.</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: I have been playing with the upload sets in the shell. It appears my problems has to do with my app not correctly using the items set up in my config. Both my upload sets seem to have the default list of allowed extensions in them, rather than the ones I've defined.

Comment: Figured it out... it's always something so stupid. I had my list of extensions as a string. Changed 'png, jpg, jpeg' to ('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg') and VOILA! Interesting to note... a list with one extension still did not work in the case of my pdf... so i had to make it ('pdf', 'PDF')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A silly stupid mistake by me:

```
UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = 'pdf'
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_ALLOW = 'png, jpg, jpeg'
```

These two lists of allowed extensions I had declared as strings... Changed them to:

```
UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = ('pdf')
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_ALLOW = ('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg')
```

However, interesting to note: The list still did not work with a single item, so I had to add two:

> UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = ('pdf', 'PDF')

Comment: I think "The list still did not work with a single item" is just a Python tuple issue. Try `UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = 'pdf',` or `UPLOADED_MANUALS_ALLOW = ('pdf',)`